# jQuery obtain links from specific child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to do the following thing ?

I have this div:

```
<div class="articleBoxContent">
   <h2><a href="myLink">Title</h2>
   <p>
      <a href="anotherLink">
        <img src="img.jpg">
      </a>
   </p>
   <p>My text is so awesome! I like ponies and cookies.</p>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery snippet:

```
$(".articleBoxContent").click(function() {
   window.location = $(this).find("h2").find("a").attr("href"); 
   return false;
});
```

What I want to do is that when I click on my div, it sends me to the link contained in the **H2** elements (myLink) ONLY if the div doesn't contain another link in the **p** elements.

But I can't figure out how to say to jQuery to differenciate links in **H2** elements from links in **p** elements. Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: `$(".articleBoxContent:not(:has(p a))").click(function() {...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
$(".articleBoxContent").click(function() {
    var el = $(this);

    if( el.find('p a[href]').length == 0 ){
        el.find('h2 a[href]').trigger('click');
    } // if
});
```

Comment: What if you use `window.location = el.find('h2 a[href]').attr('href');` in place of the trigger?

Comment: In that case, it sends to the H2 link even if it has a <p> element

Comment: it works ! Sorry, I just realized that some of my links weren't in "p" elements.... shame on me

Answer (score 0):

Do a check inside the `p` elements:

```
$(".articleBoxContent").click(function() {
    if ($(this).find("p a").length) {
        //Found some anchor elements inside a "p" tag, do nada
        return false;
    } else
        //Didnt find an anchor inside the "p" tags - redirect
        window.location = $(this).find("h2").find("a").attr("href"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: The div send to the link even if there's another link in a <p> element, so it's not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$(".articleBoxContent").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();

 var $this = $(this);

 if(!$this.find('p a').length) {
   window.location = $this.find("h2 a").attr("href"); 
 }
 return false;
```

});

Comment: The div send to the link even if there's another link in a <p> element, so it's not working :/

Comment: Try adding `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`